# AttributeError: 'StringVar' object has no attribute 'curselection'

Tags: python

Buen día. Tengo un error al momento de obtener la selección de mi Listbox. No sé qué estoy haciendo mal si todo está idéntico a otro código donde sí me funciona. Lo que intento hacer es mostrar en un Listbox una tabla de mi BD y que al seleccionar un elemento los Entry se llenen con la información diponible para modificar, una vez modificado el dato, que se guarde la actualización registrando de nuevo los datos en la tabla. ya logré hacerlo con otras ventanas pero en esta me falló y no entiendo por qué. El error dice que el objeto StringVar no tiene el atributo de Curselection. Alguna solución?

`
    #DEFINICION DEL LISTBOX

```
    self.obtenCarrera = StringVar()
    self.carrera = Listbox(self.frameCarrera, listvariable=self.obtenCarrera, width=40, height=20,
        font=("arial", 12),
        selectbackground="medium turquoise",
        exportselection=0,
        highlightcolor="steel blue",
        selectmode=BROWSE,
        yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)
    self.carrera.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
    self.carrera.insert(0, '                           CAERRERAS')
    self.carrera.insert(1, " ")

#SELECCION PARA MOSTRAR EN EL LISTBOX
    cursor.execute("SELECT c.id_carrera, '_______________', c.nombre FROM carreras as c ;")
    inforCarreras = cursor.fetchall()

    for carrera in inforCarreras:
        self.carrera.insert(2, carrera)

    def obtener():
        self.posicion = self.carrera.curselection()  # la variable hola obtiene el ídice (posición) en número de la seleccion. guarda la seleccion del cursor
        self.infor = self.carrera.get(self.posicion)  # La variable h obtiene los datos del índice (posición) seleccionados.

    # OBIENE ID USUARIO Y LA MUESTRA EN EL ENTRY
        cursor.execute("SELECT id_carrera FROM carreras WHERE id_carrera = " + str(self.infor[0]) + ";")
        self.idcarrera = cursor.fetchone()
        self.idcarrera.set(self.idcarrera[0])

    # OBIENE NOMBRE Y LA MUESTRA EN EL ENTRY
        cursor.execute("SELECT nombre FROM carreras WHERE nombre = '" + self.infor[2] + "';")
        self.nomb = cursor.fetchone()
        self.carrera.set(self.nomb[0])

# ELIMINAR#

    def eliminar():
        self.posicion = self.carrera.curselection()  # la variable posicion obtiene el ídice (posición) en número de la seleccion.
        self.infor = self.carrera.get(self.posicion)  # La variable h obtiene los datos del índice (posición) seleccionados.
        cursor.execute("DELETE FROM carreras WHERE id_carrera = " + str(self.infor[0]) + ";")
        self.carrera.delete(self.posicion)
        conexion.commit()
#MÉTODO PARA MODIFICAR
    def modificar():

        self.idus = self.idcarrera.get()
        self.n = self.carrera.get()

        cursor.execute("SELECT id_carrera FROM carreras WHERE id_carrera = '" + str(self.infor[0]) + "';")
        consul = cursor.fetchone()
        self.modif = consul[0]

        sql = "UPDATE carreras as c SET c.id_carrera = %d, c.nombre = '%s' WHERE u.id_carrera= %d" % (self.idus, self.n, self.modif)
        cursor.execute(sql)
        conexion.commit()
        messagebox.showinfo("ACTUALIZACIÓN EXITOSA!!", "        Datos actualizados correctamente. \n\n")

#LIMPIO LOS ENTRY
        self.idcarrera.set("")
        self.carrera.set("")

    self.modif = IntVar()  # variable para obtener la posición
    self.idus = IntVar()
    self.n = StringVar()`
```

Comment: Si mira la respuesta de esta pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25374355/8933039 puede resolver su problema....

Comment: Lo analizaré, muchas gracias!

Comment: No veo muy claro de dónde sale el error 'StringVar' object has no attribute 'curselection'... Eso es cierto, `StringVar` no tiene ese método, pero en lo que muestras tu aplicas el método sobre `self.carrera`, un `Listbox`... Por cierto, los métodos `obtener`, `eliminar`, etc usan lo que parecen ser atributos de instancia (por lo de `self`) pero ellos no son métodos de instancia ¿defines las funciones dentro de un `__init__`? Considera agregar la traza completa del error y si fuera posible un [mcve] a ver si se aclara el problema.

Comment: Efectivamente @FJSevilla, todas las funciones están dentro del __init__.

Comment: Vale, opino que es más apropiado hacer que estas funciones sean métodos de instancia y no definirlos dentro del inicializador, no obstante esto no es un error propiamente dicho, por eso te sugerí que agregaras la traza completa (para al menos saber la línea que lo ocasiona) y algo de más de código para poder reproducir el error. Ese error sería entendible si hicieras `self.obtenCarrera.curseselection()` por ejemplo, pero no con el código que muestras...